# Facebook lint roller: Could not retrieve data from URL

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am having an issue getting OG data back from http://conservative-warriors.com/.  Facebook won't display any content including images on the Facebook feed.  When I use the Facebook Debugger it returns a "Could not retrieve data from URL" error.

Apparently Facebook isn't getting anything https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://conservative-warriors.com/.

I have changed themes and that didn't help.  I have checked the HTML validation and the header information appears to be correct.  I have tried other sites on the same server and those are working.  I have tried updating WordPress and its plugins and that didn't help.

As of about a month ago, Facebook was getting data back.  I am at a loss as to why it is being uncooperative now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your og:url points somewhere else

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://conservative-warriors.com/want-to-see-your-ancestors-past-lives-with-new-dna-technology/">
```